# How can I get below result using nested for loop where is input is 3?

Tags: python, nested-loops

[image]

I have the code:

```
n = int(input())

l = []

for i in range(n):
  l.append([])
  for j in range(n):
      if i==j:
        l[i].append("*")
        
      
      elif i+j==n-1:
        l[i].append("*")
      else:
        l[i].append("")

      
        
      # if i+j==n-1:
      #   l[i].append("*")
      # else:
      #   l[i].append("")

for i in l:
  print(*i)
```

Which gives me , diagonals.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine, if you just adjust `n`; try putting `n = 2 * n - 1` right after the first line (for a minimal patch).

Answer (score 0):

As j1-lee said, it's enough to add `n = 2 * n - 1` after reading it.
But wanted to show alternative approach if you want to just print result:

```
string = "{0: >{width_1}}{1: >{width_2}}"
n = int(input())
for i in range(1, n):
    print(string.format("*", "*", width_1=i, width_2=2 * n - 2 * i))

print("{0: >{width}}".format("*", width=n))

for i in range(n - 1, 0, -1):
    print(string.format("*", "*", width_1=i, width_2=2 * n - 2 * i))
```

`{0: >5}.format("abc")` syntax means **reserve 5 cells to variable and put there "abc".** So to achieve that we increase width_1 and deacrese width_2 in loop, then print middle star and then deacrese width_1 and increase width_2 in loop again.